# Getting the text value of a hidden span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with columns of data (name, age, email) and I have a single modal window that is hidden and only appears when the user clicks "Detail" along side each row.

The data that needs to be populated in the modal is in hidden span tags with classes such as hide-name etc.

HTML:

```
<tr class="xrow row-2">
<td>Fisher, Baker</td>
<td>2 notes</td>
<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reviewMeetingModal">Review</a></td>
<span class="hide hidden-name">Fisher, Baker</span>
<span class="hide hidden-date">2014-03-20</span>
<span class="hide hidden-time">14:00:00</span>
</tr>
```

This is my JS that I have used, however when I call on the name variable it returns nothing.

```
$('.xrow').on("click", '.btn-review', function () {
    var name = $(this).closest('span.hidden-name').text();
    // alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Please post the related markup.

Comment: @undefined please check post

Comment: You have invalid html there - wrap those spans in td too if they are part of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in your code refers to the `.btn-review` element not the `tr`, you should at first select the closest `tr` element:

```
var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.hidden-name').text();
```

edit: Your markup is invalid, `tr` element can only have `td` child element, you should wrap the span elements with `td` elements, browsers will render this markup differently. After changing the markup the above snippet should work.

I would suggest moving the `span`s to the `td` element that has the button as it's child and then use `$(this).siblings('span.hidden-name').text()` which is more efficient than using `closest` and then `find`.

```
<tr class="xrow row-2">
    <td>Fisher, Baker</td>
    <td>2 notes</td>
    <td>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reviewMeetingModal">Review</a>
       <span class="hide hidden-name">Fisher, Baker</span>
       <span class="hide hidden-date">2014-03-20</span>
       <span class="hide hidden-time">14:00:00</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: would `parent()` selector be more suitable?

Comment: @Imran Well, I haven't seen the markup. if the button is child element of the `td`, the `parent()` method  selects the parent `td` element. If the target element is a child of another sibling `td` element then you should also use the `siblings` method. `$(this).parent().siblings().find(...).text()`

Comment: I have tried the code suggested in the answer, but it does not work. I have also tried using `.closest('span.hidden-name')` without any success however

Comment: @Imran Have you changed the invalid markup? `closest` will select the closest specified _parent_ element. I would suggest moving the span to the `td` element that has the button as it's child and then use `$(this).siblings('span.hidden-name')` which is more efficient than using `closest` and then `find`.

Comment: please update your answer to the comment above so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured what you want:

```
$('.xrow').click(function () {
    var name = $(this).find('span.hidden-name').text();
})
```

You just have to search the element you want, within the contents of the element you clicked on.

Comment: This was the initial code I had, but undefined pointed out that this will call `.btn-review` instead of `tr` so I made a modification.

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap your spans with any td. for example last td.

```
<td>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reviewMeetingModal">Review</a>

<span class="hide hidden-name">Fisher, Baker</span>
<span class="hide hidden-date">2014-03-20</span>
<span class="hide hidden-time">14:00:00</span>
</td>
```

and you can reach with:

```
$('.xrow').on("click", '.btn-review', function () {
    var name = $(this).parents('.xrow').find('span.hidden-name').text();
    alert(name);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V4z8S/2/